# Files (except pdfs) Corrupted when uploading django restframework api

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Hey so i'm having a bit of an issue. I wrote a django restframework api for uploading files to my local directory. It seems like it works perfectly fine when it comes to pdfs, but any other type of format damages the file and make it unable to open.

(this includes png/jpg/any other picture format, txt files, xlsx files, and etc)
The files are saved perfectly fine in the correct path, they're named appropriately without issue.

```
class UploadInvoiceFile(APIView):
     parser_classes = (FileUploadParser, MultiPartParser)

     def put(self, request, filename, specific_path='admin'):
         file_obj = request.data['file']
         file_path = settings.INVOICE_URL[admin]
         file = file_path+'/'+filename

         if not os.path.exists(file_path):
             os.makedirs(file_path)
         with open(file, 'wb+') as destination:
             for chunk in file_obj.chunks():
                 destination.write(chunk)



         return Response(status=204)
```

UPDATE:
I found out that the files that are curropted have additional stuff saved to them

------WebKitFormBoundaryKDALl9LeBZb6xbOo
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="123.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

file data

------WebKitFormBoundaryKDALl9LeBZb6xbOo--

Answer (score 6):

The `FileUploadParser` assumes that an incoming request is a raw byte stream and parses it as a whole. It's typically [listed on its own](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/#fileuploadparser) in `parser_classes` since it will activate for any type of incoming data.

What's happening in your case, is that you're sending a multipart request which is being picked up by `FileUploadParser` and the whole thing - boundaries and all - saved as a file. Hence you see the `WebKitFormBoundary` in the files.

You should drop `FileUploadParser` from `parser_classes` and let the `MultiPartParser` correctly parse the multipart request.

```
class UploadInvoiceFile(APIView):
     parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, )
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I came across this and realized it answered my question posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63556864/django-rest-file-upload-results-in-different-file-size-than-original
Thanks.

Comment: Briliant! This has just fixed my whole set of problems. Thanks you